# Java virtual Machine Launcher - Error: Could Not Open

Tags: java, windows-7, virtual-machine

I have seen many topics saying that the Virtual Machine Could not Create the jar file, but none that said it could not OPEN.  So I am hesitant to run the fixes I have seen.

This happens when we run a terminal emulator (on one machine) it is an IBM software
we can get past it by clicking OK a few times, but it would be nice to get it fixed.

One of my co-workers said he had the same issue and was able to fix it with a sequence of commands from a prompt, but he lost the documentation.

[image]

Here is a screenshot, you have to click OK, and there is one or two right behind it that have the same verbiage.

Comment: Reinstall Java on that machine. It's a message from the Java Runtime, not the targeted program.

Comment: As it turns out the entire directory called "lib" on C:\Program Files\IBM\Personal Communications\java\jre was missing. I ended up copying from a known good workstation the "lib" directory and all the subfolders.  I dont know i fthat was the correct thing to do or not.. but it did work.

Comment: If it works, what are you wondering about? If it doesn't work, reinstalling Java would fix it.